# Google Play Services - enhanced "contact details" window

Tags: android, google-play-services

In Gmail app on Android, in message view, if I tap the message sender's image -
- there is a very nice window with that person's details, which even includes the his/her "Google+ Banner Image".

Here is my own, to clarify of what I'm talking about:

[image: enhanced contact details window]

This works for both people present in my Contacts and those that are not.

It is *not* the standard QuickContact from the Android SDK:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.QuickContact.html

Looking at logcat output, I can see that this "improved" UI is implemented by Google Play Services:

> 08-02 22:48:28.337 I/ActivityManager(  763): START u0
>   {act=com.google.android.gms.people.smart_profile.ACTION_SHOW_PROFILE
>   pkg=com.google.android.gms
>   cmp=com.google.android.gms/.smart_profile.SmartProfileActivity (has
>   extras)} from uid 10071 on display 0

I'm unable to find anything in the Google Play Services documentation, but then there is so much of it, I could have missed it. It's probably related to Google+ but that's just a guess.

Anybody have an idea how to bring up this window / activity?

Any Google'rs willing to share the knowledge?